# ERROR: unable to load AX Bundle: MapKitFramework.axbundle. Help?

Tags: ios, ipad, mapkit, ios-simulator

I'm using MapKit in an iPad app with the Base SDK set to iOS 4.2 in Xcode 3.2.5. When I run the app in the iPad Simulator 4.2, the app works fine. When I run it in the iPad Simulator 3.2, it crashes on startup with the following error:

> ERROR: unable to load AX Bundle:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MapKitFramework.axbundle

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran my app on a 3.2 device and discovered that I was using [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationFunctions/Reference/reference.html), which is only available in iOS 4.0 and above. I replaced my call to CLLocationCoordinate2DMake with the following:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.latitude = lat;
    coord.longitude = lng;
```

Problem solved! It now runs in the iPad Simulator 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

If your base SDK is set to 4.2, all bets are off for previous versions. If you are setting up your project that way, you'd likely set the minimum required target to also be 4.2, in which case the program would fail to install on devices previous to 4.2 at all, so testing against the 3.2 simulator isn't really worth the time and effort. If you roll back to a lower version'd base SDK, you'll have compatibility with the 3.2 simulator, but may lose the more advanced features of the later framework version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sounds like you're saying that even if I set my target to 3.2 (which I have), it's still not going to work in the 3.2 Simulator. Is that right? Is there no support for the 3.2 Simulator in SDK 4.2?

Comment: my guess would be that there should still be backwards compatibility, but I've honestly never bothered to try. However, if you're using API features only available in 4.2 in a 3.2 sim, or targeting 3.2, your app either a) won't compile b) will compile with warnings (this is most likely) or c) will crash. Usually, it's safest just to target the most recent version of the framework unless you have a really great reason not to?

Comment: Thanks again. I'm not actually using features only available in 4.2. The only issue I have is with the MapKit framework, which was available in 3.2. If I remove it, I'm able to run the app just fine in the 3.2 Simulator. The problem is that I need to support 3.2, 4.2, and MapKit, and the 3.2 Simulator somehow can't handle that.

Comment: Just to confirm: you have your iOS Deployment Target set to iOS 3.2, and your base SDK set to 4.2, right? This would be in your project settings under the build tab. If this is the case, try reinstalling the SDK from scratch. I've tried with these settings, and things seem to work fine. (also, if you have an iPad to test with, that is running 3.2, that would be a good starting place too)